# I am absolutely stumped on this python programming exercise, can anyone please tell me what is wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, n-queens

I am currently doing a `python` exercise which, when given a chess board of size `n`, is to return a solution with the maximum number of queens so that no two queens attack each other.
Thus, a solution requires that no two queens share the same row, column, or diagonal.

I am currently able to generate the board, but the problem comes in line 20 of my code, where `if bd not in soln`. For some reason that I am unable to identify, that line of code does not execute properly and correctly append the correct board to my solution set.

If anyone could help to identify the problem I would be very grateful.

```
import random

def queensol(n):
    """Find the number of solutions to placing Queens on a chessboard of size n"""
    size = n
    rng = random.Random()
    tries = 0
    bd = list(range(size))
    soln = []

    while True:
        tries += 1
        rng.shuffle(bd)
        correct = 0
        for queen_index in range(size):
            if queen_noclash(bd, queen_index):
                correct += 1
        board_valid = correct == size
        if board_valid:
            if bd not in soln:
                soln.append(bd)
                print(soln)

def no_diagonal(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = abs(x1-x2)
    dy = abs(y1-y2)
    # print('dx',dx)
    # print('dy',dy)
    if dx == dy:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def queen_noclash(bd, queen):
    correct = 0
    for left_queen in range(queen):
        left_queen_x = left_queen
        left_queen_y = bd[left_queen]
        queen_x = queen
        queen_y = bd[queen]
        if no_diagonal(left_queen_x, left_queen_y, queen_x, queen_y):
            correct += 1
    if correct == queen:
        return True
    else:
        return False


queensol(4)
```

Comment: What is the expected answer to the code you have posted above?

Comment: How do you expect your `while True:` loop to terminate?

Comment: Oh i got it now, thanks a lot; have not thought of a way of terminating the while True besides adding a count +=1 if count >= a certain number, break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the bd is an object. You are appending the same object to the board. So, even though bd changes `bd not in soln` will always give False since you are comparing the same object. You should use list(bd) to create a new object every time you are appending to soln array. I have fixed this in the below code.

```
import random

def queensol(n):
    """Find the number of solutions to placing Queens on a chessboard of size n"""
    size = n
    rng = random.Random()
    tries = 0
    bd = list(range(size))
    soln = []

    while True:
        tries += 1
        rng.shuffle(bd)
        correct = 0
        for queen_index in range(size):
            if queen_noclash(bd, queen_index):
                correct += 1
        board_valid = correct == size
        if board_valid:
            if bd not in soln:
                soln.append(list(bd))
                print(soln)

def no_diagonal(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = abs(x1-x2)
    dy = abs(y1-y2)
    # print('dx',dx)
    # print('dy',dy)
    if dx == dy:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def queen_noclash(bd, queen):
    correct = 0
    for left_queen in range(queen):
        left_queen_x = left_queen
        left_queen_y = bd[left_queen]
        queen_x = queen
        queen_y = bd[queen]
        if no_diagonal(left_queen_x, left_queen_y, queen_x, queen_y):
            correct += 1
    if correct == queen:
        return True
    else:
        return False


queensol(4)
```